# How can I check if google.accounts.id.initialize() method has already been called?

Tags: google-identity

On Google Identity we are using `google.accounts.id.initialize()`.

We would like to check if the `initialize()` method was already called once. Is there a way to check that?

We tried to initialize in the `onGoogleLibraryLoadin` in order to call `initialize()` only once, but without success, moreover we would like to have a way to check if `initialize()` was already called.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.